# Origin of "Plumb" to mean "absolutely"

Tags: meaning, etymology

"plumb" as far as I know is a predominantly American usage, as in "That was just plumb crazy!"

I thought plumb meant some kind of weight in bricklaying or such like, so how did it come to mean "absolutely"? What was its origin and history?

Edit:
After Callithumpian's answer, I have a little addition:

Why is it a US usage chiefly, and why do not the British use it as much?

Comment: In my experience, **Brits do in fact use plumb** to mean "spot-on".  Eg, "that's plumb-perfect".  A company comes to mind that is called "plumb-something" (meaning perfect whatever-they-sell).  **HOWEVER** perhaps the expression "plumb crazy" is NOT used in UK (I'm not sure), and THAT is why you say "less used in the UK".  ie "plumb crazy" is (perhaps) not used in the UK, but "plumb" meaning spot-on, is indeed used.  BTW a funny one in the UK (particularly amongst builders) is "tits", again meaning "spot on."  (So, you finish installing a window .. you exclaim, "Tits." (!))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=plumb) indicates that the "completely" sense of the word was an extension of the "exact measurement" sense of the word and dates this shift back to the mid-18th:

> **plumb** (n.) 
>   c.1300, "lead hung on a string to show the vertical line," from O.Fr. **plombe, plomme* "sounding lead," from L.L. **plumba*, originally pl. of L. *plumbum* "lead," the metal, of unknown origin, related to Gk. *molybdos* "lead" (dial. *bolimos*), probably from an extinct Mediterranean language, perhaps Iberian. The verb is first recorded late 14c., with sense "to immerse;" meaning "take soundings with a plumb" is first recorded 1560s; figurative sense of "to get to the bottom of" is from 1590s. *Plumb-bob* is from 1835. Adj. sense of "perpendicular, vertical" is from mid-15c.; the notion of "exact measurement" led to extended sense of "completely, downright" (1748), sometimes spelled *plump* or *plunk*.

**Edit re: British vs. American use:**

I found this newsletter on [British plumb bobs](http://www.plumbbobcollectors.info/media//DIR_42117/DIR_120101/8de889425346cdc5ffff94edac144221.pdf) and noticed that another word used for the tool in several publications was *plummet* rather than *plumb-bob*. Perhaps *plummet* was a common enough name for the tool in England that it prevented the development of the extended sense of *plumb* as occurred in the U.S. This is only a guess.

**Edit re: confusion with *plum*:**

After seeing the *OED* references in @Simon's answer, I agree with @Peter's comment that there seems to be some confusion between the etymology of *plumb* and *plum* as intensifiers. I found this on *plum* at [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=plum):

> **plum** 
>   O.E. *plume*, early Gmc. borrowing (cf. M.Du. *prume*, O.H.G. *phruma*, Ger. Pflaume) from V.L. **pruna*, from L. *prunum* "plum," from Gk. *prounon*, later form of *proumnon*, from an Asiatic language. Change of *pr*- to *pl*- is unique to Gmc. Meaning "something desirable" is first recorded 1780, probably in ref. to the sugar-rich bits of a plum pudding, etc.

Some of the *OED* references seem to be examples of *plum* being used to mean "something desirable" rather than misspellings of *plumb* meaning "completely."

Comment: Why don't the British use it as much as the Americans? In fact, as far as I know, they don't seem to use it at all! Is there a reason why?

Comment: @Ham: See my edit as to a guess.

Comment: @Callithumpian, a pretty good guess...

Comment: "Plumb crazy" is used in en-gb, although to my surprise BNC only has one instance.

Comment: I thought a plummet was a lead stylus, i.e. a writing tool?

Comment: @Martha: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plummet) does have this definition of _plummet_, but lists it as archaic. Then again, it has the _plumb bob_ definition as archaic as well. . .

Comment: I have never, ever, ever, ever heard "plummet" in the UK.  Sounds totally bizarre.  The builder's tool with a string, is a "plumb" (you rarely say "plumb bob"), and yes the word "plumb" is used generally (but not often) to mean "spot-on". Finally I simply **do not know** if the expression "plumb crazy" is common in the UK.

Comment: @Joe: _Plummet_ seems to be a common surveying name for optical and digital devices that now do the same thing as a _plumb_. Interestingly, Googling these brings up a high number of British and Australian sites like [this one](http://www.southsurvey.co.uk/shoplevels/optical_laser_plummets/).

Comment: Hi Cali!  Are you in the UK?  All i can say is I have never ever ever ever heard the term in the UK, including amongst builders, etc. Just one report.

Comment: Plumb correct! And [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=2vQvAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA130&dq=plumb&hl=en&ei=gAj5TcPZN8yugQePlcGdDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CFkQ6AEwCTgy#v=onepage&q=plumb&f=false) is William Holloway's 1840 *General Dictionary of Provincialisms* which gives: **Plum,** *adj.* Very; as plum pleasant; very pleasant---quite pleasant as though proved by a plumb line, or measure. *Kent.*

Comment: @Thursagen: Why do you see a mystery requiring explanation in a word or phrase being used by Americans but not Brits or vice versa? There are many such words, and it seems to me the real explanation in most cases is simply "It never caught on here or there." It's probably the unusual case where you could really give a more specific reason.

Comment: A "plum" is a fruit, and one that was at one time considered highly desireable.  You may stick your thumb into a pie and pull one out, eg.  (In fact, the nursery rhyme refers to finding a valuable document in a pie.)  Unrelated (except by confusion) with "plumb".

Comment: The only regular usage of plumb in British English that I can think of is in cricket, where it is often used to describe an LBW (leg before wicket) decision where there is no doubt whatsoever that the ball would have gone on to strike the stumps.  (see http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/story/239756.html).  I can't find any information on the origins of its use in that context (it may well be that the term was introduced from another cricketing nation such as Australia) but the term would be understood by any English speaking cricket fan.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of background and examples in other answers, but I really don't see anything at all unusual in this type of 'specialised meaning'.

Plumb weights are made of lead (Pb=plumbum), and they give **straight** vertical lines. That explanation is **straight up** (absolutely true), and it's **straight to the point** (absolutely focussed).

Does anyone ever wonder why we use *straight* in such figurative senses? I can't see why the American use of *plumb* is much different.

Brits don't say it simply because it calls to mind American 'hicks from the sticks' who are invariably **plumb loco**.

Answer (score 2):

Callithumpian's answer is all you would need; except for an actual answer to 'how did it come to mean...?'  Surely 'plumb vertical' is a builder's term, meaning 'precisely vertical as measured by plumbline', and it was taken up by outsiders who assumed it just meant *very* (I have seen it as *plum* as well as the variations in the dictionary).

Comment: I would have guessed *plumb straight* rather than *plumb vertical*, but I can't find either of these expressions in Google books before 1862 (when we get *plumb straight* meaning exactly vertical), long after *plumb* was being used as an intensifier.

Comment: @Peter Shor: My pa *is* a builder, and he just says a wall is *plumb* when it's vertical. I think anyone who says it's *plumb vertical* either likes tautology or likes American slang (and doesn't know the standard meaning of the word).

Comment: @Peter: "Plumb vertical" makes sense to me: A line can't be literally "plumb horizontal". A plumb line can only measure vertical lines. Well, I suppose in some cases you could stand the thing on end, use a plumb line to make sure it's straight, and then lie it down.

Answer (score 1):

I find the 'plumb' arguments abstruse, myself.

If things can be 'peachy keen' why can't they be 'plum crazy'?

Comment: Certainly there's been much conflation of *plumb* and *plum* over the centuries.

Answer (score 0):

The history of the US slang meaning of the word goes back a bit further than the Etymonline explanation.  From the OED:

> **plumb**
>
> c.B.2.c As an intensive: Completely, entirely, absolutely,
>   quite. Chiefly U.S. slang.
>
> **1587** Misfortunes of Arthur (1828)
>   ii. iv. Chorus 41 Then rowles and
>   reeles and falles at length plum ripe.
>      **1787** Grose Provinc. Gloss., Plum
>   pleasant, very pleasant.    **1846** S. F.
>   Smith Theatr. Apprenticeship 213 Long
>   before the time arrived‥the house was
>   plum, chock full—full to overflowing.
>      a **1861** T. Winthrop John Brent
>   xxviii. 296 When we got here, I paid
>   their tickets plum through to York out
>   of my own belt.    **1882** Burdett Life
>   Penn v. 83 Penn‥wrote his wife and
>   children a long letter‥which filled
>   them plumbfull of good advice.    **1893**
>   Harper's Weekly Christmas 1211/1
>   ‘You're plumb crazy’, she remarked,
>   with easy candor.    **1897** Kipling
>   Capt. Cour. 21 You've turned up,
>   plain, plumb providential for all
>   concerned.    **1901** F. Norris Octopus
>   i. iii. 121 ‘I'll get plumb out of
>   here,’ he trumpeted. ‘I won't stay
>   here another minute.’    **1926** ‘R.
>   Crompton’ William—the Conqueror v. 89
>   Poor woman! She's sure plumb crazy!
>      **1934** A. Christie Murder on Orient
>   Express ii. ix. 136 ‘You are sure of
>   that, M. Hardman?’ ‘I'm plumb
>   certain.’    **1967** G. F. Fiennes I
>   tried to run a Railway vii. 76 In his
>   presence I was tense, tongue-tied and
>   often plumb stupid.    **1973** E.
>   Lemarchand Let or Hindrance xiv. 182
>   They must both be plumb crazy.

Comment: The 1587 *plum ripe* looks like a different expression, arising from a comparison with ripe plums falling off a tree.

Comment: @Peter: I agree. See the second edit to my answer.

Comment: @Peter: The 1587 usage is still consistent with the meaning "completely," as in "completely ripe."  Here's the full text of the quotation:  [http://books.google.com/books?id=OlsRmZAN0jcC&dq=Misfortunes%20of%20Arthur&pg=PA41&ci=93%2C768%2C799%2C312&source=bookclip](books.google.com)

Comment: It's also quite consistent with the meaning "ripe like a plum," and given the 200-year gap between that and the next occurrence, I don't trust it.

Answer (score 0):

User Callithumpian's answer above states:

> [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=plumb) indicates that the "completely" sense of the word was an extension of the "exact measurement" sense of the word and dates this shift back to the mid-18th

So I thought to enlarge the necessary previous step: how **plumb** meant "exact measurement". Each indent signifies a response to an earlier post; I omit the usernames for readability.

> [[Source:]](http://www.reddit.com/r/history/comments/2zgpyp/what_is_your_favorite_historical_word_origins/cpiy6uw) The periodic table's symbol for lead is Pb. Pb comes from the Latin name for lead which is plumbum. Sewage and water pipes used to be made out of lead, hence the occupation of a plumber.
>
> > This is also where we get the term plumb to mean vertical or straight down/up - a lead weight at the bottom on a string was used to find the vertical placement of walls or other features.
> >
> > > [A plumb bob!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plumb_bob)

Answer (score 0):

It could come from a number of sources or all of the ones that I list, it is complicated murky history that has never been recorded that I know of.

Logic =
90° to *Sane* (being **level** headed) is *Insane* (Vertical or **Straight Up**)
"Are you **Level** **headed** or just **Plumb** **Crazy** ?"
If you are "around the bend/corner" (90° to being straight headed) then you are Crazy.

Some Plumb Lines used lead weights but many different materials have been used to make the anchor for the line over the centuries. The line must be taught, it is pulled by a weight+gravity, so that it is **Square** with the Vertical. There are a number of references that can be made from a plumb line to represent Crazy but I will leave that to your imaginations to figure out.

Ok, next is the historical, and stereotype, **Crazy Romans** link to its usage.
Romans were well known for piping clean water supplies into towns from fresh water springs/sources, problem is that they used Lead pipes. The term "Plumber" comes from the Roman lead pipe installers. 
Next Roman "crazy" health issue was that they used to put lead into wine to make it taste sweeter !!!
Lead poisoning makes you go insane because it is a neurotoxin. Aluminum is no better but that wont affect you until you are 60+, it causes long term brain damage in the form of Dementia and other forms of Alzheimer's, you may want to rethink what you use in the kitchen ; )

Modern usage of the Plumb line is an influence of the Romans that used a Groma in surveying. Would not Surprize me at all if the Romans took that from either the Chinese or the Greeks.

There are many colloquialisms in English for being crazy and Plumb Nuts is used but you are more likely to hear local colloquialisms, or current pop culture terms, that are used in various Counties ("States") pending your location on the island. Plumb Crazy does exist in the UK as a saying and a Parliament as proof of it existing as a concept = X D

Answer (score -1):

*Plumb* is also commonly used in Britain in the phrase *the plumb spot*, i.e., the best possible position: e.g., in golf, *I dropped the ballon the green in the plumb spot to sink it in one*, or *I've got seats in a plumb spot to see the match*. However, it's a bit old fashioned now – tends to be used by middle aged and older people. But, hey, maybe it will come back into fashion again like *cool* (coined in the 1940s/50s, I believe, by the "hip cats"!).

Comment: You may be thinking of *[plum](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=plum)*.

Comment: What @MετάEd said. Would Jay speak of *landing a **plumb** job*?

Answer (score -1):

Just an interesting observation: lead causes people to "go crazy", so "plumb crazy" could initially have referred to just that-- the craziness caused by excessive exposure to lead.