# Meaning of "plumb" as verb

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I found in [the free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/plumb) the various meanings of *plumb* as a verb and mainly it seems to have the meaning of *explore/study/delve into*.

However, within the title of an article of the International Herald Tribune (Aug. 11, 2011), namely *Spanish case plumbs trans-Atlantic divide on Web privacy*, it seems to have the meaning *trigger*. Is that right?

Comment: Can you check the link? I can't find that article you linked to.

Comment: @Alenanno : I found the article in the web site of IHT but it has a different title. The link is http://goo.gl/JNDzL. However the title in the printed version is as above. There's another copy of the article on-line at http://goo.gl/tpWNU but again with slightly different title! The link I posted works here. Should I change it?

Comment: I did. It's all working now. :P

Comment: @Alenanno: Since the title I report and the one in the linked article are not identical, I'll remove the link to obfuscate any misunderstanding.

Comment: I see! But that's the key, now it makes more sense I guess... I guess it's better for you and for the ones who answer if you change the title here and put the link again.

Comment: @Alenanno: Yes, but that's the title exactly as it's written in the printed version - for some reason otherwise replicates of the article on the web have different titles(!). I believe the link is not really necessary since my question is not relevant to the content of the article. Hey, how about an answer? ;)

Comment: I see, you're right, leave it like this. I don't answer because I don't know the answer. :D

Comment: Possibly they changed it because it's a poor headline and even contains a basic error in "trans-Atlantic". It should be *transatlantic*.

Comment: I would like to know how 'trigger' can be a possible meaning here. I do not see 'trigger' in any context.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/234870/50720 may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plumb is "measure the depth of", and shares a root with "plumb" meaning "connect pipework" -- both come from the latin *plumbium*, meaning "lead", as a lead weight at the end of a string was an instrument for measuring the depth of a body of water, while pipes were once made of lead.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I think it's a play on words: The title originally was *Spanish case plumbs depth of trans-atlantic* [sic] *divide on Web privacy*. Plumb here means to measure the depth of a body of water;

I don't think it means trigger, you had it correctly the first time: exploring, using the first example on the free dictionary;  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/plumb
(edit)

For those who are confused, I used THIS website: http://e.mydigitalfc.com/PUBLICATIONS/DCF/DCF/2011/08/11/ArticleHtmls/Fight-for-the-right-to-be-forgotten-11082011161005.shtml ; (where the screenshot is from) in order to answer the question, in the comments below the question someone put in the correct link (It was correct for me, I couldn't open the other websites), and THAT is the link to the article I based my answer on. As you can see, it DOES say 'plumbs depth'. I did not change the title. 
[image: Screenshot website]

Comment: Note that it does not say "plumb the depths".  This is an idiom that has a meaning quite different from plumb.

Comment: divide has a depth. [Continental divide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continental_divide) and  [Plumb/Plumbs the divide](http://www.google.com/search?q="plumbs+the+divide"+OR+"plumb+the+divide")

Comment: ["Spanish case plumbs depth of trans-Atlantic divide on Web privacy"](http://e.mydigitalfc.com/PUBLICATIONS/DCF/DCF/2011/08/11/ArticleHtmls/Fight-for-the-right-to-be-forgotten-11082011161005.shtml)

Comment: @mplungian That's another mistake, it's not in the print edition.  That is to misuse the idiom entirely, it makes no sense at all, and "plumb the divide" is obscure, I would say in fact it is another mistake.

Comment: That is your opinion only. To me it makes utter and completely sense. I read: _This case will measure how deep the divide is between European and American law on web privacy_.

Comment: "Plumb the depths" is an idiom.  How many times must I repeat that?  "plumb the divide" is not. It is not what the OP asked about, in fact he *specifically mentions that*.  You can't add words to the question in an answer.  Also a "continental divide" is just a *border* usually it means a *ridge* which of course *does not have depth*.  I am done here.

Comment: The reason I answered the apparent 'non print' version is because I answered before the end of the commentstream below the question

Comment: Indeed, it says "plumb depth", but in the printed version of the newspaper it's as I posted it. First I posted the correct link which is http://www.pressdisplay.com/pressdisplay/viewer.aspx but Alenanno complained that the link doesn't work for him. So you're right about the different title. I think what matters here is an explanation of "plumb" in this context - or in both if possible. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome, sorry about the link confusion

Comment: @z7sg "how many times must I repeat that" - until you are blue in your face. Plays on words may break any rules. In MY opinion it was plumb the divide - measure the divide - possibly used in error but completely understandable. Hope you will be able to get off your tall ungulate soon ;)

Comment: @mplungjan You just don't get it, I can't help you.